# Is there some kind of standard of modbus input register?

Tags: sensor, memory, rs485, instrumentation, modbus

As the title said,
based on your experience, is there a such thing?
If no, which are the most commonly used?
for example in a sensor, the input registers as follows:

```
| Starting Address | Info        |
|------------------|-------------|
| 0x0              | Level       |
| 0x2              | Temperature |
| 0x26             | Total Flux  |
```

which is most common between manufacturers? any articles or a list about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [another answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/32153/1328):

> There are no guaranteed addresses or registers with ModBus; that's one
>   of its biggest failings (or one if it's greatest strengths, depending
>   on how (in)experienced you are in the field). There have been numerous
>   attempts to generate some kind of standard for common devices but
>   ultimately there is no way to do this since there is no standards body
>   oversight for such a thing to succeed.